ValueError: could not convert string to float 'absent'
I'm using a for loop to get an average of user's scores and I want my code to turn the word 'absent' to a zero and add it to the sum of the scores but I got an error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'absent'

Here is my code :
total = 0 
counter = 0
for i in range(5) :
    number = float(input('enter your scores in order : \n'))
    if number == 'absent' :
        number = 0
    total = total + number
    counter = counter + 1
average = total / counter
print(average)


You need to try to think about what you're doing.  You input a string.  Then, without checking to see if it's "absent", you immediately pass it to float.  So of course you get an error.  Hint:  Check for a non-number before passing it to float.  Think it through.

Apart from the error, you should think carefully what you will do if user input something that is neither a number nor "absent".

Why would you add zero to a sum? Are you familiar with try/except which you could use to manage values other than "absent" that can't be converted to float?

The error really says it all - the string absent cannot be converted to a float. You are explicitly checking for it, but you're doing that after attempting the conversion, which, as you can see, won't work.
Move the check before the conversion and you should be fine:
for i in range(5) :
    number = input('enter your scores in order : \n')
    if number == 'absent':
        number = 0
    else: # Conversion moved here
        number = float(number)
    total = total + number
    counter = counter + 1


You are trying to convert the input directly from the console at the line:
number = float(input('enter your scores in order : \n'))

You need to change your code to read a string and then check for the control word:
snumber = input('enter your scores in order : \n')
if snumber == 'absent':
    number = 0
else:
    number = float(snumber)

